# How can you do a circular expanding hide on a view? (the opposite of a circular reveal)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I want to hide a `View`, starting at a x,y coordinate and expand this hide animation outward. Is this possible?

Essentially, this is the opposite of a circular reveal. I'm fine with this being a minSdk 21.

[image]

*extra details*

I have `ActivityB` (with a transluscent background) on top of `ActivityA`. `AcitivityA` has already been created, but it's not yet visible to the user. When you click the *done* button in the bottom right corner, I want to reveal `ActivityA` by hiding `ActivityB` (using the expanding circular hide animation, which starts where the user pressed the *done* button.)

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking about this the opposite way. You say you want to hide `Activity B` but at the same time you're showing `Activity A`. 
 It's like looking at a half empty glass. It's half full and half empty. Both are true.

**Try this :**
 Show `Activity B`. When you click done, show `Activity A` (with a transparent background) and start the reveal animation.

However, if you insist on the hiding part, here's how to do it.

```
View myView = findView(R.id.awesome_card);

// get the center for the clipping circle
int cx = (myView.getLeft() + myView.getRight()) / 2;
int cy = (myView.getTop() + myView.getBottom()) / 2;

// get the final radius for the clipping circle
int dx = Math.max(cx, myView.getWidth() - cx);
int dy = Math.max(cy, myView.getHeight() - cy);
float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(dx, dy);

SupportAnimator animator =
        ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, finalRadius, 0);
animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
animator.setDuration(1500);
animator.start();
```

Instead of starting from 0, start from finalRadius.
I recommend using a transparent background for all activities to avoid [OVERDRAW](http://www.curious-creature.com/2012/12/01/android-performance-case-study/) for performance purposes.
For other users who are trying to achieve the Circular Reveal on Pre-Lollipop devices, this is the right library([CircularReveal](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal)) to do it. On pre-lollipop, it uses its own implementation. On lollipop and above, it uses the native implementation.